# How to locate a bucolic camp site when on the road in the EU?

Tags: eu, camping, rural

Is there a way to identify a bucolic camping when you are on the road and you don't manage to reach you final destination in one day. I usually have camping gear with me, but when I need to spent the night due to some delay in the trip, I always find that search quite challenging.

I usually end up in an over expensive road hotel or some dodgy camping with quite uncomfortable tent places (e.g. rocks, roots, etc).

Sometimes I end up in a very idyllic spot. It would be so awesome if there exists a standardised way to find these bucolic campings when one needs one nearby.

Comment: Would the camping site still be bucolic if there was a standard way to find one and you had to share it with 50 others using the same standard strategy to look for a camp site? Btw, wild camping is illegal in most EU countries. In some countries, violations are even likely to cause you a noticeable fine.

Comment: In case other people were wondering the same thing, 'bucolic' isn't some kind of disease, but rather the complete opposite - 'relating to the pleasant aspects of the countryside and country life; idyllic'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I don't think so, campsite owners are not aiming for as few visitors as possible. At the same time I have the impression most people prefer a 4 star camp site with all sorts of luxury.

Answer (score 3):

The [ACSI Eurocampings](http://www.eurocampings.co.uk/) site has a pretty comprehensive search engine and an app to find campsites.

Answer (score 1):

If you can read Dutch, you can use the website [*Rustiek kamperen*](http://www.rustiekkamperen.com/), or buy some of their books to bring along.  You might have to make quite a detour to pass by one of the campgrounds listed in them, though.